# WSDL to JAVA Client code, Using Apache Axis 1.4 and Jdeveloper

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, client

I am trying to generate the client code from a WSDL.
I need to work on the Jdeveloper 10g IDE.
I generated client code from WSDL using the inbuilt tool Oracle JAX-WS 2.1.5.

For a particular WSDL this tool is generating around 122 java classes that does not include the `Locator` class. While running the code, I get a class not found exception for `WebServiceLocator` class.

However, when I am using Apache Axis 1.4 ( Eclipse IDE ), it is generating 63 java classes and it also includes the `WebServiceLocator` class, but this is not generating all the required methods that are needed for authentication, though ,Oracle JAX-WS 2.1.5. is generating those methods.

I tried merging the java classes generated from Eclipse into Jdeveloper, but then I am getting a lot of errors related to method signatures.

Is there some particular reason why these two different tools are generating different client codes, and none of them complete?

Comment: By saying `but this is not generating all the required methods that are needed for authentication`, what do you mean? What methods do you needs? What kind of authentication?

Comment: For Integration of our exchange application with a particular bank we got their WSDL and need to use it at our end. The bank requires that we send a request to the bank along with an authentication header.
Using the WSDL Jdeveloper is generating a java class called AuthHeader.java which has the getters and setters required for authentication with the bank, such as 
        authHeader.setAgent_CorrespondentID(Agent_CorrespondentID);
        authHeader.setAgent_UserID(Agent_UserID);
        authHeader.setUser_Password(User_Password);
whereas, 
Eclipse is generating no such methods

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bit late, but for those running into the same issues, this might be helpful.
If you really want to use Axis 1.x authentication is done on your client class as follows:

```
MyLocator bindingService = new MyLocator();
bindingService .setPortEndPointAddress(myEndpoint);
MyPort port= bindingService.getMyPort();
((Stub)port)._setProperty(Stub.USERNAME_PROPERTY, myUsername);
((Stub)port)._setProperty(Stub.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, mPassword);
//Perform your query here
```

I would personally use JAX-WS. Use wsimport to generate the stubs (SOAPUI has a nice plug-in to simplify this). For authentication on a JAX-WS client its easiest to save the wsdl locally and export it as part of the jar then load it in the client. This removes the need for HTTP authorization required to access the wsdl in the first place.

```
URL myWsdlUrl = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("wsdl/myWsdlFile.wsdl");
MyService service = new MyService(myWsdlUrl , new QName("uri", "localpart"));
myPort port= service .getPort();
BindingProvider bp= ((BindingProvider)vPort);
bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, myEndPoint);
bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, myUsername);
bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, myPassword);
//Perform query here
```